# How do I turn off popup offers and ads in Acronis True Image 2016?

Tags: windows, backup, acronis-trueimage

I'm running a bought and paid for copy of Acronis True Image 2016 (it was an upgrade). How do I turn off their popup/toast ads which seem to be a new thing (my older version never did this)?

Here's an example:

[image]

Unfortunately my 30 support just ran out so I can't raise a support issue. Others seem to have the same problem:

> https://forum.acronis.com/forum/102762

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you cannot turn them off.  You can only select "don't show this message again" on individual notifications to avoid seeing them more than once.
https://kb.acronis.com/content/57373